# How do I prioritize the use of keyboard shortcuts for my program?

Tags: vb.net

How do I prioritize the use of keyboard shortcuts for my program?

I have a form that I want to disable some keys like Alt + F while running the program.
Problem When running another program that uses the same Alt + F keys to capture the screen, the priority is for SnagIt
I can not disable keys and my screen does not respond to disable keys.
How to disable shortcut keys used by another background program such as SnagIt

```
rivate Sub Mainfrm_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Alt And e.KeyCode = Keys.F Then
        ' When the user presses both the 'ALT' key and 'F' key,
        ' KeyPreview is set to False, and a message appears.
        ' This message is only displayed when KeyPreview is set to True.
        'Me.KeyPreview = False
        MsgBox("KeyPreview is True, and this is from the FORM.")
    End If

    ''Print (ctrl, p)  + print screen  إلغاء مفاتيح البرنت سكرين  والبطاعة 
    If e.KeyData = 131152 Or e.KeyData = 131089 Then e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: For the record, you should not be comparing `e.KeyData` to a numeric literal. You're supposed to use a combination of `Keys` values, e.g. `If e.KeyData = Keys.Control Or Keys.P Then` will detect `Ctrl+P`.

Comment: Some people use other programs and special keyboard combinations for **accessibility** reasons. Are you really trying to stop such users from using your program? Don't presume you know what other programs people are running *nor* why they choose to do so and don't try to disable other programs.

Comment: There is nothing you can do about it in your program, SnagIt steals the keystroke before you can see it.  You need to pick better shortcut keystrokes for SnagIt, Alt+F interferes too much with normal program usage.  https://support.techsmith.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001293332-Snagit-Capture-Preferences-and-Keyboard-Shortcuts

Comment: @HansPassant : is there is no a programmability to solve it. I think will add throw a method to a timer tool. method will find and catch SnagIt process and kill it.

Answer (score -1):

[now this is my code and there is a shortcut for SnagIt program which can capture my screen, because the priority for SnagIt not for my program, also my program is active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmFvV.png)

[now you can see SnagIt has working with my shortcut key, when I closing snag it my program is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyoNs.png)